# Preciso criar uma rota que altera o título do projeto com o id presente nos parâmetros da rota. Mas ao testar a rota recebo o erro 500

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, rotas

Preciso criar uma rota que altera o título do projeto com o id presente nos parâmetros da rota. Mas ao testar a rota recebo o erro 500(TypeError: Cannot set property 'title' of undefined)

Aqui está meu código:

```
const server = express();

server.use(express.json());

const projects = [];



server.put('/projects/:id', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const { title } = req.body;

  const project = projects.find(p => p.id == id);

  project.title = title;

  return res.json(project);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dê um console log em projects antes de definir a variável project, provavelmente o seu array está vazio, find retorna undefined quando o filtro não é satisfeito, find não está encontrando um projeto com esse id no seu array e está retornando undefined, ao utilizar a variável project: undefined.title, por isso a mensagem.